# Why is Paillier Cryptosystem called probabilistic?

Tags: public-key, homomorphic-encryption, paillier, probabilistic-encryption

The definition of Paillier Cryptosystem says that it is a probabilistic asymmetric key algorithm for public key cryptography. Can some body explain why it is called "*probabilistic*"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As user curious said in a other answer *probabilistic* means that the encryption of the same plaintext under the same key gives as output a different ciphertext.

This is a more general property and it is known as a basic security property: it is usually refered to as *semantically secure* or *indistinguishability* (roughly: an attacker cannot guess which one of two plaintext he provided has been encrypted). It was firstly defined and introduced by Goldwasser and Micali in their seminal paper "[Probabilistic Encryption](http://theory.lcs.mit.edu/~cis/pubs/shafi/1984-jcss.pdf)" on 1984. This property is usually achieved introducing a random token into the encryption algorithm.
A very simple way to transform any deterministic encryption algorithm into a probabilistic one is to pad the plaintext with a random string before to encrypt it and do unpad it after the decryption. Under symmetric encryption it can be easily achieved using a random IV (or counter) for a secure block operation mode (as CBC or CTR).

More precisely about Pallier cryptoscheme, the encryption algorithm uses a random $r$ element per encryption.

Encryption

- Let $m$ be a message to be encrypted where $m\in \mathbb Z_{n}$;
- Select random $r$ where $r\in \mathbb Z^{*}_{n}$;
- Compute ciphertext as: $c=g^m \cdot r^n \bmod n^2 $.

Answer (score 5):

Because each time you encrypt a message $m$, its ciphertext changes and is not the same (each time you encrypt you pickup a random element $z \leftarrow \mathbb{Z}_n^*$). If for each message there was the same ciphertext then the encryption scheme would be deterministic and would not be semantically secure or would not provide indistinguishability.